# Check if a node contains a string using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html

```
<article class="swiper-slide" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie" 
                        data-list="Home - Highlights"
                        data-name="Thor: Ragnarok"
                        data-id="19730"
                        data-brand="Disney"
                        data-position="2"
                        >
```

The page contains like 2-3 swiper-slides, I need check if "data-name" contains a particular string.

@Edit:

```
HtmlWeb _Web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmldoc = _Web.Load(Url);
            htmldoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
            try
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode x in htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='swiper-slide']"))
                {
                  //  var op = x.SelectNodes("div[@class='data-name']");
                    Console.WriteLine(x.SelectNodes("data-name"));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cant get info!");
            }
```

Sorry I forgot to post the code, I can get all nodes 'swiper-slide', but how get the data-name values?

Comment: So what's stopping you from doing that? If “The page contains like 2-3 swiper-slides” couldn't there be multiple “particular string”s?

Comment: Not at all, I just check if the string appears only least an once.

Answer (score 1):

try the following code

```
var html = @"<html>
<article class=""swiper-slide"" itemscope itemtype=""http://schema.org/Movie"" 
            data-list=""Home - Highlights""
            data-name=""Thor1""
            data-id=""19730""
            data-brand=""Disney""
            data-position=""2""
            ></article>
<article class=""swiper-slide"" itemscope itemtype=""http://schema.org/Movie"" 
            data-list=""Home - Highlights""
            data-name=""Thor2""
            data-id=""19730""
            data-brand=""Disney""
            data-position=""2""
            ></article>
<article class=""swiper-slide"" itemscope itemtype=""http://schema.org/Movie"" 
            data-list=""Home - Highlights""
            data-name=""Thor3""
            data-id=""19730""
            data-brand=""Disney""
            data-position=""2""
            ></article>
</html>";

var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var selected = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//article[@data-name=""Thor1""]/@data-name");

foreach (var node in selected) {
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

This will output

```
Thor1
```

Comment: I need only get the value inside data-name, like a list u know?
Thor1
Thor2
Thor3

Comment: Just append /@data-name to the XPath

Comment: you're looking at `div` when it should be `article `

Answer (score 0):

```
int Swipers = 0;
            HtmlWeb _Web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmldoc = _Web.Load(Url);
            htmldoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
            try
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode x in htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//article[@data-name]"))
                {
                    // var op = x.SelectSingleNode("./data-name");
                    //  var op = x.SelectNodes("div[@class='data-name']");
                    string result = x.GetAttributeValue("data-name", "null").ToLower();


                    if (result.Contains("thor"))
                    {
                       // System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Url);
                        MessageBox.Show("It Appears!");
                        sendEmail();
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                    Swipers++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cant get info!");
            }
```

I don't know if this is the best way to get what I want, but works for me at moment.